# Getting specific values from a function returned from a monad I.E. the first Int from: "Int -> (a, Int, [Int])"

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Thank you kind internet person(s) for your time.

I am attempting to implement a Monad that has type `Int -> (a, Int, [Int])` and I need to be able to pull each of those values from the Monad.

Currently I am trying to implement, fmap, return, get, and put. The problem is that I have no idea how to retrieve the values from the `Int -> (a, Int, [Int])` type.

The monad's type is defined as `newtype M a = M { run :: Int -> (a, Int, [Int]) }`
where the first **int** is the value that kicks off the computation (Like the Collatz sequence), the **a** is the result, the **Int** in the tuple is the final state (it will end up at 1 if doing the Collatz sequence), and the list of **Ints** is a log of all the computations that led up to the final state (I.E. is would be: [5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1] if the beginning int was 5)

So far I have found ways to retrieve the values in the tuple

```
newtype M a = M { run :: Int -> (a, Int, [Int]) }

getVals :: M a -> Int -> a
getVals m z = a where
    (a, _, _) = run m z

getState :: M a -> Int -> Int
getState m z = mid where
  (_, mid, _) = run m z

getLog :: M a -> Int -> [Int]
getLog m z = ws where
    (_, _, ws) = run m z
```

(The z is supposed to be the initial integer value that will kick of the computation: E.G. a collatz sequence)

but I haven't been able to retrieve the initial **Int** from the **Int** -> (a, Int, [Int])

Just to clarify I am asking for how to retrieve individual details from a `Int -> (a, Int, [Int])` type. The Monad stuff is just the context.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on exactly what you want the semantics of your type to be. If you edit your question to make that clearer (preferably also adding some examples), then I can update my answer to include how to implement more typeclasses and methods.

Comment: Tongue slightly in cheek: `getInitialInput :: M a -> Int -> Int; getInitialInput m z = z`. But only slightly; if that doesn't meet your needs, it might be worth thinking about exactly why.

Comment: It looks like you want to extract a value of type `A` from a function `A -> B`. Why do you think this is possible? If I go to the market and see a sign "1kg of apples for 1€" I can't obtain 1€ from that deal.

Comment: Are you sure you want a monad? If you just want the Collatz sequence then you can just write a recursive function for it without a monad. Or if you prefer you can use `unfold`.

Answer (score 1):

First, a stylistic point: you should redefine your tuple as a data type with named fields:

```
data MD a = MD {
   mValue :: a,
   mState :: Int,
   mLog :: [Int]}
```

Now on to the meat.

The general form of a monadic action like this is

```
myAction :: M a
myAction = M $ \oldState ->
    ... stuff ...
    MD result newState newLogs
```

The lambda argument `oldState` is the `Int` you are looking for.

Your `getState` looks like this:

```
getState :: M Int
getState = M $ \s -> MD s s []
```

So you are returning the state argument as your result, and also passing it on unchanged to the next action. No logs get written as a result of doing this.

You can't write `getLog` to inspect the current log in this monad because the log list is not being passed along as part of the state. However you can write one which takes an `M` action, runs it, and gives you the resulting log as well as writing it to the outer log.

```
getLog :: M a -> M ([Int], a)
getLog action = M $ \oldState ->
   let MD result newState innerLog = run action oldState
   in MD (innerLog, result) newState innerLog
```

You will also want an action

```
writeLog :: Int -> M ()
```

Your bind `>>=` will have the type:

```
(>>=) :: M a -> (a -> M b) -> M b
```

So your `Monad` instance is going to start

```
instance Monad M where
    v >>= f = M $ \oldState ->
```

The new log is going to be the log taken from `v` concatenated with the log taken from the output of `f`. The rest is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Thank you so so much! The \oldstate explanation helped me out better than anything my professor has taught / I've read online anywhere. I'm just now implementing what you explained but I just wanted to do a proper thank you as soon as possible.

Comment: Thanks, but the proper thing to do here is upvote, and if appropriate click on the big tick mark to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's only one way (up to equivalence) that any type can be made into a `Functor`. Here it is for your type:

```
instance Functor M where
    fmap f m = M $ \z -> let (a, mid, ws) = run m z in (f a, mid, ws)
```

As for how to "retrieve" the `Int` to the left of the `->`, that's not something that's stored in the type. You instead get access to it when the function eventually gets called. For example, in my above instance, you'd access it as the `z` variable.